# Is there a better way to copy many tables from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I'm copying about 200 tables from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS. Right now, the basic package template follows this logic:

1. Get time
2. Truncate table
3. Load data and get row count
4. Record table name, row count, and time to log table.

Currently, I copy and paste the package and change the data flow. Is there a better way to do this? I know SSIS is metadata driven, but doing 200 tables like this is a little ridiculous. And if my boss wants me to change something in the template then I get to do it all over again. Is there a way to loop through tables? I would just use linked servers in SQL Server but since we have SQL Server Enterprise I'm able to use the Attunity connectors and they are much faster.

Any help would be appreciated. It seems like there must be a better way but I'm not familiar enough with SSIS to really know what to ask for.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it looks like you can write code to generate the packages: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136025.aspx and obv you can get the column and table names from sql. I'm sure there is a copy database functionality too.

Comment: why not to put tables into some table with additional info (like copy or not) and take tables from there?

Comment: @Darka How exactly would I do that in SSIS?

Comment: I dont know. I am not using SSIS. And maybe will be bad example, but you take all tables, put this table names one by one into param and pass to Truncate, Load ... Sounds simple :D

Comment: @Darka That's what I was thinking as well and I've done it using linked servers. But I can't find how/if you can do it that way in SSIS.

Comment: Why can't you use linked servers in this case?

Comment: @ElectricLlama Linked servers are slow. The Attunity connectors are about 10x faster in my measurements and I would like to use them.

Comment: You should be able to use BIML to autogenerate your package. I have no experience with BIML but apparently that's how you do it.